# How to find in a directory tree directories containing from 2 to 3 subdirectories?

Tags: linux, bash, find

In a given directory tree i want to search directories containing from 2 to 3 subdirectories

what i have done so far:

```
find -type d -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 3
```

Comment: it is tagged as bash. I dont understand offtopic issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
find . -type d -printf "%p " -exec find {} \
       -maxdepth 1 -type d -printf "x" \; -printf "\n" | egrep ' x{2,3}$'
```

Note that this does not include any thoughts about paths with spaces in them and might lead to problems in case you want to use the output in an automated fashion *and* have nasty file names.  But if you only want to see a list of the directories, this should work out fine.